# Ant script to run junit with fork="yes" forkmode="perTest" does not create separate vm

Tags: java, ant, junit, jvm

I am relatively new to JUnit. The requirement of our JUnit project is that if the application under test is restarted, we need to create a new jvm to run our tests in for it to connect to the application.
One way I found of creating separate JVMs was by initiating JUnit scripts through ANT. Below is the the test build.xml I'm using

```
<target name="test" >
    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" forkmode="perTest">
        <formatter type="plain"/>
        <classpath refid="build.class.path" />
        <classpath refid="test.class.path" />
  <test name="test.HelloworldSuite"/>
```

I am printing the PIDs of all running java.exe processes within each JUnit test to determine if separate JVMs are being created for every JUnit test.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq java.exe\"");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
in.close();
```

Above code always prints the same list of PIDs for java.exe tasks.

Is there something missing in what I'm trying to do or is there a better way to make sure each JUnit test is executed in a separate JVM?

Comment: Which version of Ant are you using?

Comment: I see that the Apache Ant plugin version in eclipse is 1.7.1.v20090120-1145.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the *threads* attribute? The default is one, and it seems like one has to define the amount of threads to be used explicitly, even though *fork* is set to yes.
Check the manual: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

```
<target name="test" >
  <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" forkmode="perTest" threads="5">
  ....
  ....
  </junit>
</target>
```

Additional note: this will execute each Test/TestSuite in a thread. If you only have one Suite to be executed, nothing will change. If you had several suites, those will run in x threads.